# Need help making a enumerator for a linked list in c#

Tags: c#, enumeration, singly-linked-list

I am trying to take a custom made linked list class I made and make an enumerator to use with it in one of my C# programs. I don't want to show too much of my code, so hopefully this is enough.

I'm not sure, but is this what it the enumerator is supposed to look like?

```
class SinglyLinkedListEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private Node<E> node;
    private Node<E> start;

    public SinglyLinkedListEnumerator(Node<T> node)
    {
        this.node = node;
        start = node;
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get { return node.getData(); }
    }

    public Boolean MoveNext()
    {
        if (node.getNext() != null)
        {
            node = node.getNext();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        node = start;
    }

    public void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterator blocks make creating an object that implements `IEnumerable<T>`  *much* easier:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Iterate<T>(Node<T> root)
{
    var current = root;
    while (current != null)
    {
        yield return current.getData();
        current = current.getNext();
    }
}
```

It removes most all of the boilerplate code and just lets you define all of the logic for determining what the nodes in the sequence are, while still providing all of the functionality of having written out all of the code as you did.

Comment: FYI, may or may not be relevant to this Q&A, but here is a Q&A that compares use of *iterator block* to *select*: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9231736/199364

Answer (score 1):

In the C# world, this concept is called *enumerating* instead of *iterating*. Not to be confused with `enum`.

Anyway, the respective interfaces you are looking for are `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. Check out their documentation, and you should be good to go. The concept itself is pretty much identical to what you did in Java.

Comment: I looked at their documentation and I see "properties" and methods. Im not sure what properties would mean, are those the methods that are required? then does that make the normal methods optional? And I am still confused. Would I change my next() method to move()? the documentation doesn't tell me what the methods are supposed to return either, but I might just be missing it.

Comment: Properties are a language feature not existing in Java. In Java, you have getter and/or setter methods. In C#, you have properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.

Comment: Regarding MoveNext: In C#, moving to the next element and getting is is split up. You have the `Current`-Property (which would be `getCurrent()` in Java), and you have `MoveNext()` which returns true if it could advance to the next element, instead of returning the next element itself.

Comment: I updated the question showing what I have right now, could you tell me if it looks right?

Comment: Note that even in C# plenty of people still use the term *iterating*.  It's not really wrong to use it.

Comment: This also doesn't really answer the question at all.  It's pretty much a comment posted as an answer.  Clearly the OP is already familiar with `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`, having written proper implementations of both of them...

Comment: @Servy: Check the date on both the question and my answer. This is what the question looked like when I answered: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16724452/1 And in that context, my answer made perfect sense, even the part about Iterator vs Enumerator. Unfortunately, the OP decided to remove all this later.

Answer (score 1):

**Enumerator for linkedlist** should look like this:

```
public class MyLinkedList : IEnumerable        {
        Node head = null;
        Node current = null;

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()            
        {
            current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                yield return current.Data;
                current = current.Next;
            }            
        }
```

While node itself

```
public class Node 
    {
        public int Data;
        public Node Next;
        public Node(int value) { Data = value; }            
    }
```

**For Binary tree** you should implement all of three: Current, MoveNext and Reset + don't forget about Constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `Node<T>` code looks like but this looks odd:

```
public Boolean MoveNext()
{
    if (node.getNext() != null)
    {
        node = node.getNext();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Ideally, it seems MoveNext would look like this:

```
public Boolean MoveNext()
{
    // make sure current node is not null
    if (node != null)
    {
        node = node.getNext();
    }

    // simply return whether current node is null or not
    return node != null;
}
```

In your initial method, you are getting the next node twice which *could* give you false results. I assume `getNext` simply returns a reference to the current node's next sibling.  Otherwise, I don't see any initial problems with your enumerator (or iterator) class.

For clarity, I would use `currentNode` instead of `node` and change `start` to `startNode`. <strike>In addition, if `node.getNext()` doesn't return a Node object, then the method should be renamed to indicate what it is doing.</strike>

I made the assumption that `node.getNext()` was moving an internal reference but @Servy corrected me. Thanks!

I might still recommend some name changes to clarify the operation. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that `node` isn't itself an iterator, it's a node. It's next node is fixed.  Calling `getNext` doesn't mutate the node to change it's next node.  While your change does make it a bit cleaner, his code isn't *wrong*.

Comment: Thanks @Servy ... seems that some assumptions can be made about the OP's code that might not be accurate then. ;)

Comment: It seems like a pretty safe assumption to make.  You're making the assumption that calling `GetNext` will change the node's internal reference to it's next node.  What's your basis for *that* assumption?  I see none.  The OP also indicated that his code works, he just wants to know if it's good practice.  That he has indicated his code works makes my  assumption pretty safe.

Comment: My assumption was based on this line: `if (node.getNext() != null)`. I was in *Enumerator.MoveNext()* mode. I agree with you though that my assumption was in error.